# We need to send out emails from Salesforce

Tags: email, apex-email-service

We are dealing with big customer and our contacts emails are huge and it may vary from one day to another. We definitely understand this can’t be achieved in Salesforce because it will hit the Salesforce governor’s limit (10000 per day).

We are using the Salesforce platform to build our business application. Now we reached the place where we can’t achieve this feature in Salesforce.
We looked into third party tools which will meet our requirements. But here we have faced some challenges which are listed below.

1. We can’t able to send the mail merge
2. We can’t able to bind the values in email attachment(Mobile Bill: Spilt of the each mobile bill per user)

As I understand that Salesforce in not meant for the sending the mass email, if Salesforce would have this feature that will be great I feel.

So I am posting this question because Salesforce can able to give the solution for this and let me know any tool which should provide the feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

With apex emails having such strict limits, have you considered using a workflow email fired on record insertion?  This approach will allow for "The daily limit for emails sent from workflow and approval-related email alerts is 1,000 per standard Salesforce license per organization".